# MySQL using BETWEEN clause with AND clause & OR clause

Tags: mysql, sql, between

I want to run a query where you select every data between *date1* to *date2* that has status of *Confirmed* or *Reserved* grouped by status.

But the code I'm trying,

```
select * from reservation where (date(bdate) between '2013-2-4' and '2013-2-8') and status='Reserved' or status='Confirmed' order by status
```

doesn't seem to work.

I need to fetch the data within the date range only that has either *Confirmed* or *Reserved* status. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from   reservation 
where  date(bdate) between '2013-2-4' and '2013-2-8' and 
       status IN ('Reserved','Confirmed')
order  by status
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use query like this

```
select *
from reservation
where date(bdate) between '2013-2-4' and '2013-2-8'
    and (status = 'Reserved'
      or status = 'Confirmed')
order by status
```